# Can't remember security questions and rescue email ends with .cim instead of .com so I can't use it to reset my questions

Tags: security, apple-id

My cousin wanted to buy something from the app store. I let her use my account to do so. It asked us to answer security questions but I couldn't remember them. So I tried to reset it but the link to reset my questions ended in .cim instead of .com. So I couldn't send a link to reset them. What should I do?

Comment: it only asks to answer security questions if you try to log in not from your device. So try to log in from your device and fix the email.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has support personnel to help with Apple ID and purchase issues.

- http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201485

You can use the "if you don't have a rescue email address" link to get in touch with a human. You may want to search for the answers and/or see if you have another old email address as the rescue address in addition to the one with a typo. Also, if you can document what purchases you have made in the past that sometimes helps establish your identity when calling or emailing in to support.

They will have a script to see if they can help you based on your particular account and how you set it up.